# Not able to fetch the user liked music , movie and pages when user is logging in using facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have created a web application where i am trying to fetch the user information like (user liked movies , music and pages ,name and user-id) when user is logging in app using facebook login . Its fetching all these information absolutely fine for me but its not working for other users who are logging in application using facebook . Do i need to submit my web application for review to get the access for all these information ? Because when i am trying to check the permission for those users its showing grant permission for public_profile and email only .
Please , suggest me how i can fetch the information for other users as well .

Comment: Of course you need to submit for review. When you tested your app with an admin or developer account, the login dialog already showed a big, red warning telling you that you would have to do that, and the documentation also mentions this all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

> You do not need to submit your app if it will only be used by you or
>   by a reduced number of people. Any account listed in the Roles tab in
>   your App Dashboard, such as admins, developers and testers, can use
>   all permissions.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/what-is-login-review

You can either add users in the App, or go through review. The docs offer all the information you need on Login Review, i suggest you read all of it.

Comment: HI - I have already gone through this document and i want to fetch the information for the users without adding him in any role (just like a normal user) so for this do i need to submit my web application or is there any other go ?

Comment: you have to send additional permissions to review. there is no other way.